# Back one item before in a for loop after a certain condition is meet

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am working with selenium and inside my function I have to do some operations several times, the point here is when I get 40 iterations on that page, the selenium breaks and I need to restart the function. I've already solved this by putting a count variable that when a certain number of iterations are met, selenium will close the controller and reopen it, but here's the problem, when this happens, the element in the for loop where the count variable meets the condition is not taken when selenium is restarted, this goes to next item in my list.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
```

```
def prueba(n=2):

    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chromeOptions.add_argument('log-level=3')
    chromeOptions.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": os.getcwd(),
                  "directory_upgrade": True}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities(),executable_path='/Users/kev/Documents/Proyectos/Selenium/chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.mx/")


    count = 0

    for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
        if count < n:
            if i == 'a':
                try:
                    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
                    print('a')
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            elif i == 'b':
                try:
                    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
                    print('b') 
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)        
            elif i == 'c':
                try:
                    driver.get("https://www.twitter.com")
                    print('c')
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)   
            else:
                try:
                    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
                    print('d')
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

            count+=1
            print(count)

        else:
            count = 0
            driver.close()
            print('Esperando 5 segundos...')
            time.sleep(2)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities(),executable_path='/Users/kev/Documents/Proyectos/Selenium/chromedriver')
            driver.get("https://www.google.com.mx/")
            continue
```

```
prueba()
```

So here when I run my function everything works fine but when i = 'c' the count variable is meet, here the function passes to the else statement resetting the count variable and the Selenium, and when starts again it goes directly into 'd' instead of continue with 'c'

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't seem to be correct. The for `loop` you define is hard set at doing four iterations `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. With each iteration, it adds 1 to the count. When it gets to 'c', the 3rd iteration, the count is 2. So it fails the first conditional.

Instead, you should specify either a nested for loop:

```
n = 2
for _ in range(n):
    for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
        # Do Stuff
```

Or use a while loop with a counter.

```
n = 2
counter = 0
while counter < n:
   for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
        # Do Stuff
   counter +=1
```